# How to deal with suggested edits from the original poster using a different account?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The situation is this: there is [the following suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/243421) on a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215513/horizontal-wise-add-pdfptable-with-multicolumntext-in-itext). From the edit it seems to me that [the user suggesting it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343043/lingadurai) is actually the same as the original author. Perhaps he logged in for his edit, while he did not do so before. Either that or he has gone beyond all that can be reasonably expected and written all this code to clarify the question.

In such a case, are we to accept the edit under the assumption that the users are the same? Worst case scenario, if we're wrong it can always be rolled back, right? I would have liked to clarify this issue with the user anyway, but couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: `Can't be more clear than that.` Actually I had no idea what you are talking about until I read the second paragraph. A better title would be `How to deal with suggested edits from the original poster using a different account?`

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast It was more or less tongue-in-cheek anyway, since I couldn't come up with a more non-descriptive title than that. Excellent suggestion. I'll change it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes most likely it's the same person - the account he used to ask got deleted for some reason but nothing prevents him from creating new account - no spammer or something like this.

So approving such an edit is fine, although the ideal solution would be to have that new account merged with the deleted account if possible. I flagged that question now asking such a thing, but maybe it should come from the person himself with some proof he's the same as the one who posted the question.

Answer (score 4):

The edit seems to be adding lots of information to the question.

It is unlikely to be from someone other than the OP (possibly a colleague) - as a useful edit, I would approve it. Doesn't matter if it is from the OP or not.